# The sentence with the 'on sb way out' pharse

Tags: sentence-meaning

From [the dicitionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/way-out)

> By 1989 it was clear that she was already on her way out.

I didn't get the point of this. Was the sentence talking about two women (`she` and `her`)? Couldn't you explain the meaning in more simple words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example sentence follows the definition:

*no longer successful, popular, or effective*

Since the definition does not mention more than one person, the example sentence does not refer to more than one person. The **point** of the example sentence is to demonstrate how the meaning *no longer successful, popular, or effective* can be used in a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

No, they refer to the same person.

> on her way out

is a phrase meaning your involvement or popularity was ending. For example,

> She wasn't a very good teacher, and this year it was clear she was **on her way out**.

meaning that she wasn't doing a good job, and would likely be disciplined or fired soon.

This term can also be commonly used referring to show biz and politician popularity.